# Rails 3 - client_side_validation and how to work with checkbox?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, model, client-side-validation

I am using on my pages `client_side_validation` and everything works fine. But now I have in my form 2 checkboxes and I need to check the user fill one of them (I used jQuery for denied to fill both).

I am trying to fing the way, how to do validation rule in my model for getting, that the checkbox was filled.

If I want to check my input (if contains some string), I'll use:

> validates_presence_of :email, :message => "Some message"

But I don't know, how to do the same for checkbox... In my form is:

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :item %><br />
    Val_A: <%= f.check_box :item, :value => 0, :checked => @data.item == 0, :class => 'checkboxes'%>
    Val_B: <%= f.check_box :item, :value => 1, :checked => @data.item == 1, :class => 'checkboxes' %>
  </div>
```

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ensure that one – and only one – of two options is selected, then you should use radio buttons not checkboxes.